# KeyBoard shortcut for moving code to the left

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, code-block

I have this following code in one of my SO question ,

```
public IQueryable<Materials> GetMaterial(int id)
    {
        return from m in db.Materials
                        join Mt in db.MeasurementTypes on m.MeasurementTypeId equals Mt.Id
                        where m.Mat_id equals id
                        select new Materials()
                        {
                            Id = Convert.ToInt64(m.Mat_id),
                            Mat_Name = m.Mat_Name,
                            Mes_Name = Mt.Name,
                        };
    }
```

Look at the code from the forth line it is far right so that vertical scroll bar is seen...
I have to select all the code from the 4th line till `};` and move to left still further so that i can eliminate vertical scrollbar.......
I tried `Shift+Tab` what it does it takes focus to the title textbox... Any suggestion...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy/paste it into a decent texteditor, use the unident feature, paste it back.

Answer (score 1):

To outdent, like you want, you can select the indented lines (ensure to select *whole lines*, not partial lines) and click the "code" button or press Ctrl-K. That will not allow you to indent code further though: it will indent 4 spaces if there's no indenting yet, or outdent one step in all other cases.

As an aside: it's also best to use spaces, not tabs, and certainly not mix them. See [How does The Editor Handle Tab Characters?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43131/how-does-the-editor-handle-tab-characters)