# Change link colour for links to deleted question?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, deleted-questions

Many links on MSO are back to questions that have been deleted on SO, but for a <10k rep user these just show the 404 page instead. So my suggestion is: if my rep isn't high enough to allow me to follow a link, **can that link colour be changed to indicate that so I know not to bother ?** I'll work on improving my rep in the meantime :)  It's really frustrating clicking links from MSO and seeing that 404 page over and over.

Any chance of this happening ?

Comment: not a bad idea! +1

Comment: Minor (er...) implementation issue: I believe the HTML is the same for all users. For example: the [automatic-titled-raw-trilogy-links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title/69483#69483) are inserted whenever a post is saved. That is: the title that is current *while saving* is shown, not the title that is current *while viewing* the result. And changes are not reflected until the post that uses the link is saved again. (So, I think the whole HTML is generated when a Markdown post is saved, though I'm not 100% sure about that.)

Comment: Well I can imagine from a dev point of view this may be quite a challenging request for various reasons, as you'd need to check the status of each linked page against the users rep on a different domain (MSO vs SO) to be able to set the css. But I'm hoping it can be implemented whatever the technical difficulties, as it'd definitely be a usability improvement.

Comment: @Arjan It could be implemented even having the same HTML for all users, by having an ajax call on document.ready() . That would then change the CSS for the appropriate links for the appropriate users, while leaving it unchanged for others.

Comment: Assuming caching of the generated HTML is done to speed up things, I doubt Ajax would be used to categorize links. In that case it might to easier to use some CSS class for 10k+/moderator-only links, and expire the cached HTML every now and then. That would also fix old link titles.

Comment: (Jeff calls this [cooked HTML](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48596/when-does-the-question-answer-text-get-converted-from-markdown-to-html/48598#48598).)