# Lining things up in the editor — disparity between preview and post

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor, markdown-preview, markdown-rendering

Yes I know I am being a bit nitpicky, but *I like things lined up in neat little rows, damnit.*

In the preview it looks great:

[image: Image of Preview]

but on the post it lines up according to the editor, not the preview:

[image: Image of Result]

Comment: As [described here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77552/please-make-table-previews-match-actual-output/77555#77555), the problem comes from using tabs in the markdown. Unfortunately it seems that there's still an inconsistency between how the server and client side handles that situation, though.

Comment: You could at least have made your question demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @Tim client side issue makes perfect sense. Thanks.

@hans I think the images I linked demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Probably caused by mixing tabs and spaces, see [How does The Editor Handle Tab Characters?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43131/how-does-the-editor-handle-tab-characters/83420#83420)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tim Stone is correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89391/lining-things-up-in-the-editor-disparity-between-preview-and-post#comment-222024); this resulted from an inconsitency between server-side and client-side tab handle. [This is fixed now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77552/please-make-table-previews-match-actual-output/90548#90548), and [as you can see](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5843312/edit), the preview now looks like the rendered version.