# Turn off Markdown formatting

Tags: support, markdown

Markdown formatting makes easier to write good looking questions and answers, but sometimes people use ASCII art (like above) to create tables or other symbols to make their question/answer more clear.

> [image: ASCII table]

This is very handy if it is treated as raw text, but characters in these arts are Markdown keywords too, so it will turn these into something like this:

> [image: Markdown styled ASCII art]

Even if we put the ASCII table to a blockquote or a code sample it still displayed wrong. For example in this question: [MySQL and PHP Many-to-Many Database Relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092452/mysql-and-php-many-to-many-database-relationships)

[image: Formatting ruined alignment]

Here you can see that this process ruined the allign of the vertical lines.

Is there a way to turn off the Markdown converter tool so the pasted ASCII table will be displayed as plain/raw text? Some keyword/function like:

```
<rawtext>
Plain text here.
</rawtext>
```

If no, could we implement this function? Or in the other hand how should we treat ASCII tables/illustrations like this?

Comment: Do you have an example of a situation where a code block is not enough?

Comment: you can put it in a `<pre>` or wrap it in a code block with `<!-- language: lang-none -->` (to avoid coloration)

Comment: never use the tab character inside code block formatted text. Actually tabs should be instantly and irrevertibly burninated and converted to four spaces when copy pasting. On the link you've sent the code block uses tabs instead of spaces.

Comment: Mixing tabs with spaces from the look of it. Disabling markdown wouldn't fix this, as there is no agreed-upon standard for what width a tab should be. Use spaces.

Comment: Although I asked something that can be solved with the site's features I don't think it deserves that many downvotes. It is a well formated/described question/problem that others can face too, so it is a good reference.

Comment: Downvotes have different meaning here on Meta. They signify agreement or disagreement with what you've posted, not the quality of the question asked. The [faq] can provide more information.

Comment: `<rawtext>`, almost like *pre*-formatted text?

Comment: I have a feel that you guys want to punish me with your downvotes...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use code blocks (4 spaces) with `<!-- language: lang-none -->`and *NEVER* use <kbd>tab</kbd>s inside them, [as they can be misleading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43131/how-does-the-editor-handle-tab-characters):

So this:

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->

    --------------------------------------------
    |                colour                    |
    --------------------------------------------
    |     colour_id     |     colour           |
    --------------------------------------------
    | 1                 |     blue             |
    --------------------------------------------
    | 2                 |     red              |
    --------------------------------------------
    ############################################
    --------------------------------------------
```

becomes this:

```
--------------------------------------------
|                colour                    |
--------------------------------------------
|     colour_id     |     colour           |
--------------------------------------------
| 1                 |     blue             |
--------------------------------------------
| 2                 |     red              |
--------------------------------------------
############################################
--------------------------------------------
```

After copy-pasting you can use the `{}` button to indent all your lines with 4 spaces (so they become code blocks). You will still need to remove all <kbd>tab</kbd> characters, and replace them with spaces though.

Related posts:

- [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)
- [Enable tab and shift + tab for code formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174966/enable-tab-and-shift-tab-for-code-formatting)
- [Add increase/decrease tab indent buttons to the editor toolbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8144/add-increase-decrease-tab-indent-buttons-to-the-editor-toolbar)

And the best meta topic ever:

- [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/43134#43134)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `<pre>` for this, as it's still sensitive to certain HTML characters like `<` and `>`. Indenting by four spaces is better.

Comment: That language identifier doesn't actually do anything. It just gets stripped as invalid HTML. Manual `<pre>` blocks *never* get syntax highlighted. Only Markdown-produced code blocks are eligible for syntax highlighting.

Comment: yeah, you're right. changed the answer

Comment: @animuson That's not quite correct. Anything that's `<pre><code>` *will* be prettified, whether Markdown-created or handwritten. You're right though that `<pre>`-only block never will be; they're not code after all :)

Comment: @SztupY Can you clarify the problem with tabs you're describing? Ever since I [rewrote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90548/115866) the PageDown (then WMD-New) detabber, the tab behavior should be well-defined and consistent (not that that means you should be using them, of course).

Comment: @balpha: The problem is that when you create a new post an paste in a `tab`, some browsers (tested with Chrome) will ident it to 8 chars, instead of 4. Therefore when it gets posted what was visible during posting (8 spaces) will become 4. The only solution for this would be if a javascript would automatically convert `tab`s into 4 `space`s while creating / editing a post.

Comment: @SztupY That's not right. The Markdown preview indents to four, not eight spaces. The only thing that may be displayed differently by browsers is the content of the input box.

Comment: @balpha: that's what I'm saying. People usually look only at the input box when creating posts, especially code blocks, as they think that will just be exactly the same as in the input box (so "no need" to check the markdown rendering). And they're almost right: it will be the same. Except for the `tab` characters.

Comment: @SztupY "People usually look only at the input box when creating posts" -- that's really a [citation needed].

Comment: @balpha: sorry for the weasel words. I took that from the amount of posts I've seen inside the review queues having some of this issues.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `<pre>` tag to work around this. For example:

```
--------------------------------
| colour                       |
--------------------------------
################################
```