# How to preserve a TAB character in a string?

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting

I want to preserve the TAB character in a string, because I want to give an example input that contains a TAB. Then users can copy that string and use it. But it seems like StackExchange always converts TABs into spaces, even inside a code block. (In markdown, TABs are preserved in code blocks.)

In the original StackExchange editor textarea, the whitespace between `a` and `b` is a TAB character. But in the preview, and after posting, it gets converted into spaces.

`a  b`

Is there anyway to keep the TAB and prevent it from being converted into spaces?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43131/how-does-the-editor-handle-tab-characters